# Looks fine in XML but cramped at top while running the app

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

Hey guys I made a app it is not very complex as I am still in learning phase. I am currently learning app dev and as soon as a reached the intent part a very amazing idea came to my mind . It uses basic button , image view , textview and multiactivity or intent . So I made it scrollable and it looks completely fine in the XML design but when I fixed few errors and ran the app . All the text and image views were cramped at the center top . Any fix on why that happened?

I tried to gpt few fixes changed the layout from constraint layout to linear layout . But nothing has worked

Comment: Without the code, there's nothing we can help with.  Post the xml and a picture of what it actually looks like.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! You need to give us more information so we can help with your problem. Please edit your question and show us the XML layout file content. Also attach a screenshot of what it looks like on the device/emulator.